# FreeSwitch Mod_Event_socket Events handling

Tags: freeswitch

Hello Freswitch Geeks,

I am facing some challenge handling events with the mode event_socket. I create a socket library that implements some of the features of the mod_event_socket in-built ESL. This what I did: I connect to Freeswitch, subscribe to events via events command and execute an originate command using the socket application. When the call is answered FS connects back to a daemon app runnning and based upon this guideline https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Event_Socket_Outbound#Using_Netcat I am able to handle the call.

However the issue I am facing is some of the events are not received by the deamon app(for instance channel_hangup_complete, record_stop...) I would like to know whether I am missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

from the link you posted

> it's a race,
>
> sometimes the socket connection ends before the channel
>
> the linger socket command was added to tell FS to wait for the last
>   channel event before ending the connection
>
> just send the command
>
> linger

This is an api command, so you will need to run "api linger" or something similar

Comment: The "linger" command is only available when using the the full api. You must specify "async full" in the dialplan.